# Unable to select Pro edition during Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10

I would like to upgrade from Windows 10 Home to the Pro edition. When I double-click the setup.exe file in the Windows 10 installation media, the wizard sets Home edition as the default, and there is no option to change it to Pro edition. However, if I run the setup.exe in the same media on another PC running Windows 10 Pro, the wizard will use Pro as the default option.

So the question is how can I make the Windows 10 installation media give me opportunity to choose other editions other than the default one? Thanks!

**Update:** Eventually I worked it out by following [this trick](https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-cant-select-pro-edition-during-windows-10-installation/). What I did is to create a text file named **PID.txt** under the **Sources** subfolder in my installation media, and put my Windows 10 Pro key in it with the following format:

```
[PID]
Value=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Comment: I think you have to upgrade the home to pro by applying a pro key...

Comment: Yep. I've downloaded the latest build of Windows 10 and made a USB installer. But the setup keeps using the product keys in the UEFI firmware and doesn't let me change the edition or enter a new product key.

Comment: Try to inserting new pro key in home settings...

Comment: Looks like you found the solution by yourself! However, considering Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, questions should only contain the problem, and solutions should go to the "answer" section. It'd be great if you [post the solution as a new answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer), and remove it from the question!

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro, you'll need a valid product key or a digital license for Windows 10 Pro for the device you're upgrading. You'll have a digital license if Windows 10 Pro was already installed and activated on your device.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro

Comment: When running the setup from within Windows, it doesn't give me options to enter product key at all. The setup can detect the product key embedded in the UEFI firmware, but I want to apply a different product key.